# My web scraper is not scraping all the comments and usernames

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote a code to scrape all the comments and usernames on a reddit post but the code isn't scraping everything,

What might be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

listt = []
count = 0
username_list = []
comment_list = []

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"}
url = input("Please input reddit url:")
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

old_page_url = "https://old"+url[11:]
old_page = requests.get(old_page_url,headers=headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")
old_soup = BeautifulSoup(old_page.text,"html.parser")

comments = soup.findAll('div',{'data-test-id':'comment'})

for one_comment in comments:
    comment_list.append(one_comment.text)

for name in old_soup.find_all("a"):
    listt.append(name.text)


for item in listt:
    if item == '[–]':
        username_list.append(listt[count+1])
    count+=1


for i in range(len((comment_list))):
    print(f"Comment made by u/{username_list[i]} = {comment_list[i]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that other comments will only load when you scroll down?

Anyway, if you need to get all comments & username, use Reddit API itself:

`https://www.reddit.com/comments/{thread-id}.json`

For example: https://www.reddit.com/comments/iv5jaa.json will show all comments from https://www.reddit.com/r/DeepRockGalactic/comments/iv5jaa/.

Use JSON parser to work with it :).

Comment: can u help me find any youtube video or course that will help me work with json?

Comment: this should be a good start for you: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp